# Inspecting source code with vim, ctags and other tools

Tags: python, vim, ctags

There is plenty of information about how to browse source code with vim/ctags, like jumping to a tag, navigating tag stack, searching for a tag match, etc.

However, I can't find information about how to actually inspect source code and its structure, similar to something like "source browser" tool in some IDEs.

The following is what I want to be able to do with Python source code using vim, though the same may be equally true for some other languages:

1. List all members of the current file (module), i.e. top level classes, functions and/or variables defined in the module.
2. List all methods and attributes of a given class.
3. Jump to a member within a given class, i.e. something like `:tag ClassName.my_method`.
4. List package members/hierarchy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of what you want (the "listing" part, at least) can be done with [TagList](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=273) or [TagBar](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3465) but I'm afraid you are confusing Vim with an IDE.

Comment: Why do you think I am confusing vim with an IDE? I can see that tags file provides enough information to make some common tasks in inspecting and navigating unfamiliar code easier.

Comment: Tags are helpful, yes. But not *that* helpful compared to the accuracy of the information you can get in an IDE. Vim can't deal with scope, for example, it can't jump you to `Class.method` if the tag is not *exactly* `Class.method`, and so on… I think that you are confusing Vim with an IDE because you seem to expect it to have IDE-like capabilities.

Comment: What is an IDE but an editor with enough plugins stuffed in?

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at Rope?

http://rope.sourceforge.net/ropevim.html

> ### Features
>
> ## Rope refactorings:
>
> - Rename anything!
> - Extract method/local variable
> - Move class/function/module/package/method
> - Inline method/local variable/parameter
> - Restructuring (like converting "${a}.f(${b})" to "${b}.g(${a})" where "a: type=mymod.A")
> - Introduce factory
> - Change method signature
> - Transform module to package
> - Encapsulate field
> - Replace method with method object
> - And a few others...
>
> ## Rope can:
>
> - Extract similar statements in extract refactorings
> - Fix imports when needed
> - Preview refactorings
> - Undo/redo refactorings
> - Interrupt refactorings
> - Perform cross-project refactorings
> - Handle basic implicit interfaces in rename and change signature
> - Support Mercurial, GIT, Darcs and SVN in refactorings
>
> ## Rope can also help IDE's with:
>
> - Auto-completion
> - Finding definition location
> - Getting pydoc
> - Finding occurrences
> - Organizing imports (removing unused and duplicate imports and sorting them)
> - Generating python elements

http://rope.sourceforge.net/index.html

Comment: Rope is awesome.. but does it support viewing the functions/modules etc in a tree like structure like `gutentags/tagbar` does?